# Authorization frameworks for HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4, authorization

I have an MVC website with RazorView, where I have hundreds of html elements.
I wanted to enable or disable some fields,allow or deny edit on some text fields ..etc..
Is there any javascript framework that I can use? Or what is the best approach to implement element level authorization?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you check permissions on client side (Javascript), you have to validate it on server site. Otherwise, it could be possible to manipulate a request and fill fields where you don't have permissions.

So I can't advise a framework which matches your question, but make sure you proof data on server side also - no matter what you're using on client side.

Thus, a solution might be to hide fields (serverside template) where a user has no permission.

Comment: Thanks ihkawiss . I am doing server side validations on my Controller.  What I require is just enabling and disabling fields in html based on auth levels.

Comment: Ok. I assume it would be the cleanest / fastest solution if you write it on your own. You could give each field a attribute which represents it's permission level. Then check each field (on document ready - jQuery) against user's permission and disable restricted fields.

Comment: ok. I can do that. But I am searching for a scalable solution. Also, iterating through each dom element might hit the performance is my worry.